# Need IPC solution for 2 proceses on same machine

Tags: go, ipc

I have a situation where I have 2 processes, A and B, both on the same machine. Process A needs to send some state information to process B. For Process B, I have no control except when Process A dies, a handler is called on Process B which I can edit.

Now, how can I reliably send the state information from Process A to Process B. Note again that I only have a hook (handler) that is invoked when A dies.

As I see it, I cannot do IPC/Client-Server based solution of any sort because

1. if A is client and B is server, A will get connection refused because server on B is started only in the handler which is called after A dies.
2. if B is client and A is server, B will get connection refused because A (and server) is dead already.

The only solution I see is to persist the state information on the filesystem to a well known path/location. That way A can write to it and B can read from it.

Any other ideas? Am I missing anything?

Other things

Both processes are golang.

B is parent process of A.

This needs to work on Linux, Windows and Darwin.

Comment: You cannot change the code for B except for that one handler called when A dies? Then you can't do any communication, just have A write to a file somewhere and B pick it up after it dies.

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately, I cannot. The code for B is a 3rd party package and it only exposes this one hook to be called when A dies.